# find files containing space and specific string in their filename and rename it

Tags: ubuntu, command-line, regular-expression, rename

By default when we copy and paste a file in same directory Ubuntu creates duplicate file and renames it to `origname (copy).ext`.

But I want to rename all those files such that the files like those names be renamed to `origname_copy_02082016.ext` means with todays date at the end just before extension.

How can I do that with `regex` and `rename` command ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are several `rename(1)`s out there, and they use different sets of options.  Assuming your `rename(1)` supports Perl expressions, this should work:

```
rename -n "s/ \(copy\)/_copy_$(date +%d%m%Y)/" *
```

The `-n` option shows you what `rename(1)` would do without actually renaming anything.  Remove `-n` when you're happy with the result.

Comment: Thanks man, it works, +1 for suggesting `-n` for review, one query, can I remove `space` from regex and it would match filename like `news(copy).txt` ?

Comment: @VickyDev Sure, you're supposed to modify it to suit your needs, not apply it blindly.

Comment: No, just some regex things I applied didn't work, so I asked. Nevermind, will try myself and check with `-n`.